# sprintf not declared in scope?

Tags: c++

I have a small snippet of code here from something I designed but I keep getting the error :

```
sprintf not declared in scope
```

Do I include something in the #includes or how can I get this working? I was working on it on VS at my mom's but came home and I can't get it on code blocks

```cpp
if (tmp2 <= B_dest[hr - 6])
{
    sprintf(name, "B%d", tmp3);
}else{
    sprintf(name, "A%d", tmp3);
}
```

Comment: The header dependencies can be different depending on the compiler you are using, you should always include the proper headers though, to figure which ones you need use a [good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to include `stdio.h`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

The `stdio.h` declares the function `sprintf`, Without the header the compiler has no way of understand what `sprintf` means and hence it gives you the error.

In C++ Note that,

Including `cstdio` imports the symbol names in `std` namespace and *possibly* in Global namespace.
Including `stdio.h` imports the symbol names in Global namespace and *possibly* in `std` namespace.

The same applies for all c-styled headers.

Comment: Now i am getting atoi not declared in scope and shouldnt it use the same thing? Its not working for that now

Comment: I did but it isnt working mabye i didnt include it in the peroper cpp file?

Comment: @soniccool: Perhaps, You need to be sure you are including the header file in the cpp file in which you use the function.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you've `#include <cstdio>`

and access sprintf as `std::sprintf()` as pointed by @Potatoswatter.

or do the old c-style: `#include <stdio.h>` to include the definition of *sprintf*.

Comment: And by the way, when using the `<c...>` headers it's best to prefix the names as in `std::sprintf`.

Comment: What's with the not putting a space before the `<`? This is a serious question, I've seen lots of people do that and I don't understand why.

Comment: @Zack: I believe the answer *"Because it doesn't matter whether you put that space or not."* wouldn't satisfy your curiosity?

Comment: @Als I am aware of that; that does not clarify why anyone would deliberately make their program harder to read in this fashion.

Comment: Busted! and corrected. Yes, I agree it adds to readability. I guess was in hurry... :D

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with C::B and found that the problem is more than just compiler paths - it seems that the IDE itself had problems opening #include <...> files -- this however could be solved by Settings -> Editor -> Other settings -> use encoding when opening files : default

my encoding was not on default, and this somehow caused problems for the IDE to open include <...>

It however did NOT solve the problem with "was not declared in this scope"